# Suggesting mandatory tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I noticed that most questions on Money SE fall into the categories

- taxes
- financial investments
- real estate

If you think about it, these categories, though distantly related, are really very different. There are many subsites on SE that are much closer related with each other.

I understand that traffic plays an important role and there just might not be enough interested users at this moment to allow the creation of subsites. But to just throw it all in one common pot doesn't seem right, too.

I don't know if it's even technically possible but if it is, I would suggest that each question must be qualified as one of the above mentioned categories (plus "other"), and that questions on taxes need to have a country or at least region tag. Those few tags should be available on the starting page of Money SE for filtering. Because if half the questions page is filled with very US specific tax questions, non-US people might feel they're in the wrong place.

Hope this makes sense.

P.S. The tags don't have to be made mandatory per se. But if their use is suggested and the starting page would show the filters, as I've seen on other SE pages, users might be inclined to use them to their own advantage.

Comment: I wonder why the negative votes, and without any comment at that?

Comment: Not sure but your first half of the post suggest we break this site into 3.

Comment: I understand that. That's why I suggested the tags as an alternative to breaking it up. As an example, check out the SE page for Ubuntu. On the top of the questions list, you have a number of tags you can use for filtering. That's what I'm proposing here.

Comment: Sorry couldn't see much different at http://askubuntu.com/. The related tags show up on money as well, on the right side.

Comment: My mistake. I wasn't joined to the Ubuntu community and it looks different then, so I mixed that up. Anyway, my suggestion still stands, I think it would benefit the site to have an internal partitioning into 2-4 larger topic groups, and to reduce the US bias.

Comment: @vic Downvotes in the meta site are typically indication of disagreement with your proposal, not that it is a bad question.

Answer (score 4):

As far as it being technically possible, the meta sites already have the "required tags" feature; each question on meta must be tagged with at least one of the required tags: discussion, feature-request, support, or bug.  However, I'm not aware of any non-meta site with this feature.

I'm not in favor of adding a "required tags" feature on Money.SE.  There are a few reasons.

First, it would be too limiting.  You mentioned taxes, investments, and real estate as the top three, but actually, real estate is only our 13th [most used tag](https://money.stackexchange.com/tags), with 373 questions out of our 12,000+ total questions on Money.SE.  Credit card questions are nearly twice as common.  However, even if we correctly identify the three most common broad topics for questions, it doesn't make sense to require these; our [on-topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page lists 10 categories of on-topic questions, listed in three headings: Investing & Saving, Spending Wisely, and Sole Proprietorships.  We don't want to give the impression that questions that do not fall into the top three tags are not welcome here.

In addition, I think that an "other" tag would not be a good idea. It would not be very useful, and I believe it would be unprecedented; I've never seen an "other" tag on an SE site.

I am also not in favor of splitting our current site into separate sites. I would personally prefer the opposite; I wouldn't mind seeing the scope of the site expanded a little.

Although it might not be intuitive, it is already possible to do lots of [advanced filtering around tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17003), including multiple tags and NOT tags, so if you'd like to eliminate questions tagged "united-states", you can do so. If you are only interested in real estate, you can filter for that.