# Recommending a nationality/jurisdiction tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

Educated reading:

- [Suggesting mandatory tags](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2195/suggesting-mandatory-tags)
- [Could a regional tag (or a new "international" tag) be made mandatory?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/423/could-a-regional-tag-or-a-new-international-tag-be-made-mandatory)
- [Suggestion: Require new users to include their country in user profile](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/606/suggestion-require-new-users-to-include-their-country-in-user-profile)

I would suggest that the "ask question" wizard **suggests** the opportunity to indicate a jurisdiction in the tags. I am not pro requiring users to declare their location in the profile, as the question **may well** be related to another country. As well as some questions may be international, or simply *location-neutral*.

But a simple reminder `Have you forgotten your jurisdiction?` could be helpful. I see a handful of questions where jurisdiction is either guessed by participants or simply asked to the OP.

Comment: "I would suggest that the "ask question" wizard suggests the opportunity to indicate a jurisdiction in the tags" — Is this actually possible? If so, that would be great. But would these regular suggestions annoy the long-time users?

Comment: Of course there must be a code change to associate the tags the jurisdiction attribute. If a user enters a nationality tag, the warning does not appear